# Edit with a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

**Issue**

I'm encountering a problem when editing a form with a belongs_to relationship (extra_guest belongs_to age_table).

I am able to create a new extra_guest and assign it to an age_table, but I cannot get the edit/update to work as my update function returns a falseClass.--> `@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params).errors.full_messages` returns `` undefined method `errors' for false:FalseClass ``

**Code**

models

```
class ExtraGuest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :age_table
  validates :age_table, presence: true
end

class AgeTable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park
  has_many :extra_guests, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :age_from, :age_to, presence: true
  validates_associated :extra_guests
end

class Attraction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park

  has_many :extra_guests, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extra_guests, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attractions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :age_tables, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :currency, presence: true
end
```

extra_guests_controller

```
def edit
    @extra_guest = ExtraGuest.find(params[:id])
    @age_table = @extra_guest.age_table
    @age_table_list = AgeTable.where(park: @attraction.park)
  end

  def update
    @extra_guest = @attraction.extra_guests.find(params[:id])
    @age_table = AgeTable.find(params[:age_table])
    authorize @extra_guest
    if @extra_guest = @extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @attraction = Attraction.find(params[:attraction_id])
      @extra_guest = ExtraGuest.find(params[:id])
      @age_table_list = @attraction.park.age_tables
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

private
  def extra_guest_params
    params.require(:extra_guest).permit(:name, :age_table_id,
      extra_guest_prices_attributes: [:id, :name, :price_type, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :duration, :duration_min, :duration_max, :backend_only, :weekend_extra, :_destroy])
  end
```

views/extra_guests/form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@attraction, @extra_guest] do |f|%>
     <%= f.input :age_table, :as => :select, :selected => @age_table.id, :collection => @age_table_list.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :include_blank => false %>
<% f.button :submit %>
```

**Error message + params**

```
Couldn't find AgeTable without an ID

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l8HMnVIRybZg==",
 "extra_guest"=>
  {"age_table"=>"104",
   "extra_guest_prices_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"price"=>"1.0", "weekend_extra"=>"", "start_date"=>"2019-10-15", "end_date"=>"20-09-2019", "duration"=>"", "duration_min"=>"", "duration_max"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"42"},
     "1"=>{"price"=>"1.0", "weekend_extra"=>"", "start_date"=>"2019-10-15", "end_date"=>"2019-10-16", "duration"=>"", "duration_min"=>"", "duration_max"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"43"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save new option",
 "attraction_id"=>"185",
 "id"=>"55"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you say you have an error with this code `@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params).errors.full_messages` but the code you show does not have that line.

Now, the `update` method returns false if it fails https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update

This line:

```
@extra_guest = @extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)
```

will set @extra_guest to false if it fails, you don't need to set @extra_guest, just use `if @extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)`

Using the line of code you name but it's not on the code you showed,`@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params).errors.full_messages`, if there are errors then `@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)` will be false, so no `.errors` method is found.

you have to split it in two lines:

```
@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params) # after this, @extra_guest will have the errors hash set
@extra_guest.errors.full_messages # call it on the object and not on the result value from the update method
```

EDIT: you are permitting `age_table_id` but the parameter is `age_table`, fix the name of the parameter to be `age_table_id` too

Comment: Thank you for helping debugging. It worked and after I was able to see the error messages, it appeared to be a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you tried to use @attraction before defining it. You could fix this by moving your definition of @attraction further up in the method, but I would move it into its own method like so:

```
private

def attraction
   @attraction ||= Attraction.find(params[:attraction_id])
end
```

Then you use the method name, which is now defined for the whole controller and invoked when you use it (as opposed to an instance variable which will just be 'nil' if you invoke it without defining it). The ||= allows the method to return the existing value of the instance variable if it is defined, rather than running the query every time the method is called. So first line of your update action would be

`@extra_guest = attraction.extra_guests.find(params[:id])`

I would do something similar for the other instance variables you have there (@extra_guest, @age_table, and @age_table_list should be defined in private methods separately). Incidentally, using a lot of instance variables for a single controller (you have 4 in this controller, which is a lot) is considered a bit of a code smell, but you should make something that works first and then refactor. Reference for later: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers